# bmatrix no new row

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I use:

```
\[
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

and as a result i have only one row. 1 is combined with 3, 2 with 4 etc. What does can cause it?

when used

```
\begin{equation}
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

result the same.

I use `\usepackage{amsmath}`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: remove the last double backslash from the last row. It expects a new row

Comment: With just this code and only loading amsmath I have no problem. Which packages do you load?

Comment: I'm afraid you're using a style file or class that tampers with `\baselinestretch` and `\arraystretch`. You can see problems also in the `cases` environment at the top of the page. A minimal example is needed.

Comment: And, additionally, there should be: (...) $S$ --- współrzędne $x$, $y$ na obrazie przestrzeni etc. (improper font and spacing) and Jeżeli wyznaczono macierz $A$, jedynym krokiem (...) Zanim jednak to nastąpi, należy (lack of commas).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you could do:

1. As people in the comments said you should try without the backslashes
2. You can try `array` instead:

> ```
> \begin{align} M=\left[
> \begin{array}{c c c c c} 
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
> 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
> \end{array}\right]
> \end{align}
> ```

`array` works the same way as `tabular`(for math mode) so you have to say how wide your matrix has to be. The other thing is that you have to open and close the matrix with `\left[` and `\right]`. I personally like to use it for more complicated matrices because it gives you much more control.